# groupby and foreach in a list in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, foreach, group-by

Hope someone can help me telling me what is wrong with the following code because I don't get the expected result as it is in the book "Head First Kotlin".

```
data class Grocery (val name:String, val category:String,
                    val unit:String, val unitPrice: Double,
                    val quantity: Int)

fun main() {
    val groceries = listOf(Grocery("Tomatoes", "Vegetable", "lb", 3.0, 3),
                            Grocery("Mushrooms", "Vegetables", "lb", 4.0,1),
                            Grocery("Bagels","Bakery", "Pack", 1.5,2),
                            Grocery("Olive Oil", "Pantry", "Bottle", 6.0,1),
                            Grocery("Ice Cream", "Frozen", "Pack", 3.0,2))
    groceries.groupBy { it.category }.forEach {
        println(it.key)
        it.value.forEach { println("     ${it.name}") }
    }
```

The result I get is the following:

```
Vegetable
     Tomatoes
Vegetables
     Mushrooms
Bakery
     Bagels
Pantry
     Olive Oil
Frozen
     Ice Cream
```

When as in the book I should get:

```
Vegetable
     Tomatoes
     Mushrooms
Bakery
     Bagels
Pantry
     Olive Oil
Frozen
     Ice Cream
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or it is because I use kotlin 1.3.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you should obtain from that input list is the one you are obtaining so there are two options here:

1. the book is wrong
2. you are using a different list as input than the book's one

The category of `Tomatoes` is `Vegetable` while the category of `Mushrooms` is `Vegetables`.

They are two different categories. If you want to group them, you should use the same category (both `Vegetable` or both `Vegetables`), otherwise you should implement a way more complex algorithm which supports the grouping by plural and singular nouns under the same category.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. It was my mistake with the plural and singular of "Vegetable" and "Vegetables"